# For what values of $x\in \Bbb N$ is $\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{360}{x}\right)$ rational?

Tags: functions, trigonometry

For what values of $x\in \Bbb N$ is $$\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{360}{x}\right)$$ rational?

Just wondering if there is any method to accomplish this.

Comment: I think none...

Comment: Obviously there is atleast one arctan(360/360) is 45 degrees

Comment: the convention is that $\tan^{-1}$ maps to radians

Answer (score 1):

According to the celebrated work of Lindemann proving the trascendence of $\pi$, also $\tan(\alpha)$ is trascendental for all algebraic $\alpha\neq{0}$. Hence, because of $\frac{360}{n}$ is algebraic the given expression cannot be rational.